# Calling a VB.net Function from VBScript

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

In my aspx page I have a button and onClientClick I am calling a vbScript function. I need to use VBScript as the third party ActiveX supports only vbScript.

OnClientClick I am populating couple of ASP.net textboxes. How do I call a VB.net procedure that is in the code-behind from vbScript.

As I cannot call both OnClientClick and onClick of the buttons at once, How do I call the server Side procedure from vbScript.

Comment: Not quite understand what your problem. The ActiveX component is a server-side one? Was it previously used in ASP scripts?

Comment: I just need to call a vb.net function from vbscript.

Comment: @acadia:  You need greater clarity in you question.  Reading between the lines you have IE on the client running VBScript.  Having handled an input type=text onclick event you need to emulate the standard ASP.NET onclick post back.   Does that cover it?  If so please include this detailed description in your question.  Failure to include good details is the reason your question has remains unanswered for 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, so I'm not sure it has been solved. As has been pointed out it lackes some details, but just for the fun of it I'll provide a possible solution. From what I understand I would do the following. From vbScript call a (web) service or an aspx-page. Have this service/page return a JSON object with all necessary values. JSON is just text, so it can be easily parsed to fill the text boxes.